# Woocommerce: How to ensure that the text/box that appears under the cart does not move when a product is updated or removed from the purchase?

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have set a text that appears permanently below the cart page in Woocommerce(and I want it to always remain there).

The question is that when the cart is updated or I delete a product that same text is automatically uploaded along with the rest of the notifications such as 'Updated Cart'.

I would like that text to always be underneath (as I have it configured in the hook) and not to move when a product is updated or removed.

How could I do it?

This is the text that I have integrated into the functions.php of my theme:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart', 'function_woocommerce_after_cart' );
function function_woocommerce_after_cart() {
    echo ('<div class="woocommerce-info">texto </div>');
    
}
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that .woocommerce-info class, which is then targeted by Ajax and moved above together with the other WooCommerce notices once you update the Cart.

It's as simple as changing that class, and apply CSS instead:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart', 'function_woocommerce_after_cart' );

function function_woocommerce_after_cart() {
    echo '<div class="after-cart-notice">texto</div>';
}
```

And:

```
.after-cart-notice {
    background-color: #3d9cd2;
    margin-bottom: 2.617924em;
    margin-left: 0;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #fff;
    clear: both;
    border-left: .6180469716em solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    padding: 1em 2em 1em 3.5em;
}

.after-cart-notice::before {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.05em;
    left: 1.5em;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

Comment: Perfect!

I have verified that it works.

Thank you very much for the help.